# Getting :before pseudo element to use background image of parent

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Can CSS be used to set the background image of a :before pseudo element to the same as it's parent. I want to say inherit, but can a pseudo element inherit anything? Example:

```
li a {
    background: #f56a46 url(images/gallery-thumb.jpg) center center no-repeat;
}

li a:before {
    background: inherit;
}
```

I know I could easily do it with JavaScript but I want to know if it's possible using only CSS. Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Yes I've tried it. Inherit does not work, but then I wasn't expecting it to as before isn't a child of the link. What I'm asking is if there's a way that accomplishes what I want.

Comment: Actually, it is a child of the link. As to why the background isn't being inherited I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Inherit` must work for pseudo-elements: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/GaUsp/

Are sure, you've added all the needed properties like `content`, `display` and dimensions so the pseudo-element have a box where background must be shown?

Comment: Sorry it does, I'm being completely stupid and missed the class that changed the background which was then being inherited. I hate it when I make completely obvious mistakes that make me doubt myself!